# Hide URL directory Using Codeigniter route

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

In my Codeigniter route, The Original URL is 
**example.com/store/items/12**
and I want to change it into
**example.com/12**
The number 12 is a **Dynamic** number.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple routes for your URL :

Routes can be :

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'store/items/$1';
```

**Note :** Please add this routes in APP_PATH/application/config/routes.php

I Hope it will help.